# AJAX request failed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

```js
function ajax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
}
xhttp.open("POST", "abcdef.xyz/abc/logincheck.php?mail=abc@gmail.com&password=abc", true);
xhttp.send();
```

```html
    <p id="demo">
    The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
    </p>
    <button onclick="ajax()">
    Click on me!
    </button>
```

I have a code as seen above and the ajax operations do result in failure. What is wrong with my code? The text in p never changes.The php file starts like this:

```
<?php
$mail = $_POST["mail"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

Comment: did you define xhttp within the function?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's web dev console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xhttp.open()` and `xhttp.send()` need to be inside the `ajax()` function.

```
function ajax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "abcdef.xyz/abc/logincheck.php?mail=abc@gmail.com&password=abc", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

due to xhttp.open and send are define out side of function block.

```
xhttp.open("POST", "abcdef.xyz/abc/logincheck.php?mail=abc@gmail.com&password=abc", true);
xhttp.send();
```